# Possible to create a 'Master Step' within Cucumber (java)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

Possible to create a 'Master Step' within Cucumber (java)?

For example I have created many steps files which use repeated code, the repeated code initialises the browser etc within each of the step files.

Is it even possible to create a master step file which will which will house the driver setup etc and therefore execute the setup using 'Cucumber Before' before each of the steps.

My Code:

```
public class LoginStep {

WebDriver driver;
LoginPage loginPage;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\deltaUser\\Desktop\\CucumberFramework\\PimCucumberFramework\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\other\\chromedriver.exe");
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
}

@Given("^User is on the PIM login page$")
public void user_is_on_the_PIM_login_page() throws Throwable {
    loginPage.loginIntoAccount();
    // loginPage.test();
}

@And("^enters the correct username$")
public void enters_the_correct_username() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("User neters the correct password inside the password textefield");
    // loginPage.test2();
}

@And("^enters the correct password$")
public void enters_the_correct_password() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Entered the correct password");
}

@When("^clicks on the login button$")
public void clicks_on_the_login_button() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Clicked on the login button");
}

@Then("^user should be taken to the successful login page$")
public void user_should_be_taken_to_the_successful_login_page() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Succesffully taken to the login page.");
}
```

}

I have tried the following code listed below, but the code dosnt work it seems to open the browser but then the other steps dont work (As if it has created a separate instance of the driver):

```
public class MasterStep {
WebDriver driver;
LoginPage loginPage;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\gianni.bruno\\Desktop\\BuyAGiftCucumberFramework\\PimCucumberFramework\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\other\\chromedriver.exe");
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
}
```

}

Comment: I would solve this using dependency injection and inject the setup functionality. It would allow me to compose the things I need and not inject functionality using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use the concept of Inheritance.

**Step 1:** Create a Base Class

```
package com.base;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestBase2 {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    public void initialize() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/com/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Inherit this class using the **extends** keyword and call the `initialize()` method whenever you need.

Comment: thanks is there a specific reason for setting the driver to static?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber provides Before and After hooks you could use for this.

Hooks are blocks of code that can run at various points in the Cucumber execution cycle. They are typically used for setup and teardown of the environment before and after each scenario.

Before hooks run before the first step of each scenario.

Annotated method style:

```
@Before
public void doSomethingBefore() {
}
```

Lambda style:

```
Before(() -> {
});
```

After hooks run after the last step of each scenario, even when steps are failed, undefined, pending, or skipped.

Annotated method style:

```
@After
public void doSomethingAfter(Scenario scenario){
    // Do something after after scenario
}
```

Lambda style:

```
After((Scenario scenario) -> {
});
```

The scenario parameter is optional, but if you use it, you can inspect the status of the scenario.